# SQL GROUP BY while displaying the most recent date in each column, without subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Given a table with this subset of rows:

```
POSTS TABLE
id      person_id      ig_post_date    fb_post_date
...
1           5               NULL        2018-03-24
2           5           2018-03-21         NULL
3           5           2018-03-22         NULL
4           5               NULL        2018-03-21
...
```

Is there a way to aggregate these results grouped by *person_id* and display the most recent *Instagram post date* AND most recent *Facebook post date* without using subqueries? I can't put my finger on the correct *JOIN* / *GROUP BY* / *ORDER BY* query to end up with this:

```
person_id      last_ig_post_date    last_fb_post_date
5                  2018-03-22          2018-03-24
```

Comment: You tagged both MySQL and SQLite. Which is it you are using?

Comment: I can actually use any since my db can be transposed using a different driver, so I tagged all. Is it causing problems and it would be preferable that I keep only one?

Comment: Well, different databases support different SQL dialects so the answer can be very different depending. For example, PL/SQL and T-SQL are very different.

Comment: I was hoping for a simple solution using very basic methods that every SQL language used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select person_id, 
max(ig_post_date) last_ig_post_date, 
max(fb_post_date) last_fb_post_date
from posts
group by person_id;
```

Comment: Whaat?? "max" will work with dates? That would be by far the simplest solution?

Comment: Yes, `max` will get you the latest dates.

Comment: Thanks heaps, friend! Kudos for the very simple answer doing exactly what I needed. By the way, I meant to say: "That would be by far the simplest solution!"

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use MAX, something like:

SELECT person_id,MAX(ig_post_date),MAX(fb_post_date) FROM mytable GROUP BY person_id

Comment: Thanks @Miguel, another user answered the same answer just a few minutes before unfortunately, so I had to give him the accept